# Where are the /images of Application Express in Oracle11gr2

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Where are the /images of "Oracle Application Express 5" in "Oracle 11g r2" and how can I modify theme CSS files easily ?

-Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are at the location you placed them when installing the Oracle Rest Data Services (Apex Listener). For a development environment this location can be on a shared drive somewhere so you can access and modify them from your development machine.

Answer (score 0):

Unix:

```
   cd $ORACLE_HOME
   find . -type d -name images
```

will list all directories named "images" starting at $ORACLE_HOME.